# Use a SAS Stored Process in ASP .NET Visual Studio. SAS integration technologies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sas, sas-stored-process

I have some SAS Stored Processes. When i run the stored processes in SAS Enterprise Guide I get some HTML returned. 
What i would like to do is make my ASP .NET project connect to the Stored Process and return the HTML in my ASP .NET application. 
I know that i'm starting from zero, so is there some articles or guides I should follow to begin with?

I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy - you have to register your STP to have `_STREAM` output (using SAS Management Console) then create your SAS code *without* the `%stpbegin` / `%stpend` macros so that they `put` your HTML directly to the automatic `_webout` fileref.

Your ASP .NET project then simply needs to call the STP via the URL (using CURL or whatever).

An even easier way is to create the web service programmatically, eg:

```
%let appLoc=/Public/app;  /* Configure Metadata or Viya Folder location here */
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/all.sas";
%inc mc; /* compile macros */
filename ft15f001 temp;
parmcards4;
  proc sql;
  create table areas as select distinct area from sashelp.springs;
  %webout(OPEN)
  %webout(OBJ,areas)
  %webout(CLOSE)
;;;;
%mp_createwebservice(path=&appLoc/common,name=appinit,code=ft15f001,replace=YES)
```

More info on https://sasjs.io

It's worth pointing out that you may not even need ASP, as your web / browser client is also able to connect to SAS directly.  This can be done via ajax, but for a consistent approach, I'd recommend the SASjs Data Adaptor.  It's available on github here: https://github.com/sasjs/adapter

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Helped a lot. Now I have something to begin with.